# Css как сделать чтобы изображение было по центру

Tags: css

https://vk.com/im?sel=206691271&z=photo206691271_456240810%2Fmail155797
https://vk.com/im?sel=206691271&z=photo206691271_456240811%2Fmail155798

как мне сделать чтобы при увеличении масштаба .lol был по центру?
делаю сайт резиновым

```css
  a:active {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: slategrey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

ul {
  background: #f6f9bf;
}

.nav {
  background: #f6f9bf;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 240%;
}

html {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

header {
  background: #f6f9bf;
}

body {
  margin: 0px!important;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("masina.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.lol {
  margin-top: 51%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 106%;
  background: #f6f9bf;
  padding: 0px 303px 0px 300px;
}

.lel {
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 7%;
  padding-right: 7%;
  left: 2%
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.lole {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2200px;
  left: 100px;
  padding: 100px 100px 10px 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #f6f9bf;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 100px;
  background: #f6f9bf;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: none;
}

input,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input,
textarea {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.lp {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1903px;
  height: 80px;
  background: darkgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3500px;
}

.contact {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3200px;
  margin-left: 100px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="class.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#top">
                    ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tope">
ЦЕНЫ
                </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#topes">
КОНТАКТНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ
                </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#to">
О НАС
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="screen">
  </div>
  <div class="lol">
    <p>
      <a name="to"></a>
    </p>
    <img src="fignya.png" align="center " width="1300px" height="500px">
  </div>
  <div class="lel">
    <p>
      <a name="tope"></a>
    </p>
    <table cellspacing="0px">
      <tr>
        <td>Марка</td>
        <td>Цена самовывоза</td>
        <td>Цена с доставкой</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>m100</td>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td>3500</td>
        <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>m200</td>
        <td>4500</td>
        <td>5000</td>
        <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
        <tr>
          <td>m400</td>
          <td>5509</td>
          <td>6000</td>
          <td><a href="#">Заказать </a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
      <a name="top"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="lole">
    Обратная сзязь ,Оставте ваш номер<br> телефона и мы вам перезвоним<br>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
      <br><input type="text" class="form_name" pattern="^[А-Яа-яЁё\s]+${1,17}" required placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
      <br><input type="tel" class="form tel" required pattern="[0-9+]{9,11}" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" name="num">
      <br><textarea type="text" class="form zak" required placeholder="Ваш заказ" name="text"></textarea>
      <button class="some-form__button" name="but">Отправить</button>
      <?php
        if (isset ($_POST['but']) ) {
            require_once 'sms.ru.php';
            $smsru = new SMSRU('C3A6B841-6B90-4FD6-4ED5-B4FFB841F914'); // Ваш уникальный программный ключ, который можно получить на главной странице
            $name = trim($_POST['name']);
            $num = trim($_POST['num']);
            $text = trim($_POST['text']);

            if(empty($name)){
                echo "Поле имя пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }

            if(empty($num)){
                echo "Поле номер пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }

            if(empty($text)){
                echo "Поле заказ  пусто. ";
                /*Выход или редирект*/
            }
            if(!empty($name) && !empty($num) && !empty($text) ){

                $data = new stdClass();
                $data->to = '89065906733';
                $data->text = $name . "-" . $num . "-" . $text; // Текст сообщения

                $sms = $smsru->send_one($data);// Отправка сообщения и возврат данных в переменную
                if ($sms->status == "OK") { // Запрос выполнен успешно
                    echo "Сообщение отправлено успешно. ";
                    echo "Ваш новый баланс: $sms->balance";
                    sleep(10);
                    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                } else {
                    echo "Сообщение не отправлено. ";
                    echo "Код ошибки: $sms->status_code. ";
                    echo "Текст ошибки: $sms->status_text.";
                    sleep(10);
                    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

                }
            }

        }?>

  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <h1>Контактные данные:</h1>

    <q>89023425523 </q> <q>5zcvxz@mail.ru</q> <q>5xhsxry@gmail.com</q>
    <p>
      <a name="topes"></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="lp">

    <br><br><br> 2018 Все права защищены. Bet.inc
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается можно применить text-align:center
и это действует если даже там нету текста жест кароче